# Error: InvalidParameterException: Task definition does not support launch_type FARGATE

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate

I use Terraform to create ECS I got error

```
"InvalidParameterException: Task definition does not support launch_type FARGATE"
```

I checked other solution from other post but it does not help. Can anyone tell my why I got that error?
**container-definition template**

```
[
    {
        "name": "api",
        "image": "${app_image}",
        "essential": true,
        "memoryReservation": 256,
        "environment": [
            {"name": "ALLOWED_HOSTS", "value": "${allowed_hosts}"}
        ],
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-group": "${log_group_name}",
                "awslogs-region": "${log_group_region}",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "api"
            }
        },
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 80,
                "hostPort": 80
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**ecs.tf**

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "api" {
  family                   = "${local.prefix}-api"
  container_definitions    = data.template_file.api_container_definitions.rendered
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = 256
  memory                   = 512
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.task_execution_role.arn
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.task_role.arn
  volume {
    name = "static"
  }

  tags = local.common_tags
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "api" {
  name            = "${local.prefix}-api"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.main.name
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.api.family
  desired_count   = 1
  launch_type = "FARGATE"
  network_configuration {
    subnets = [
      aws_subnet.public_a.id,
      aws_subnet.public_b.id,
    ]
    security_groups  = [aws_security_group.ecs_service.id]
    assign_public_ip = true
  }
  load_balancer {
   target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.ecs_tg.id
   container_name   = "api"
   container_port   = var.app_port
 }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to use task definition ARN, not family, i.e., `task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.api.arn`.

Comment: I solved this by delete `volume` in `aws_ecs_task_definition` It seems that volume is not a valid param.

Comment: Nope: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition#volume

Comment: I read docs again I think I got this error because  I added `volume` in `aws_ecs_task_definition` but I did not have `mountPoints` in `ContainerDefinition`